# NotRegistered with djcelery + Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, djcelery

I've been stuck on this one for the last 6 hours or so. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using djcelery on a Django app which is deployed on Heroku. Said app has a periodic task that works just fine.

Today, I brought up another Heroku App which is a clone of the previous one so we'll have a production environment. The new Heroku deployment doesn't run the periodic task, instead, I get this in the logs:

```
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]: [2013-01-09 15:35:11,252: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.UpdateWowza[611aad8e-a1fc-4d6e-b6df-f09b9dcf8e41] raised exception: Task of kind 'tasks.UpdateWowza' is not registered, please make sure it's imported.
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 301, in worker
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]:     result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 312, in_fast_trace_task
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]:     return _tasks[task].__trace__(uuid, args, kwargs, request)[0]
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/registry.py", line 20, in __missing__
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]:     raise self.NotRegistered(key)
2013-01-09T15:35:11+00:00 app[celeryd.1]: NotRegistered: 'tasks.UpdateWowza'
```

This is where I am stuck, the two deployments have the exact same code, same Heroku addons and same configuration.
In addition, djcelery's DB models are empty in both deployments.

What am I missing? Are there any other factors involved other than the ones above?
I even gave the periodic task an explicit name to make sure that's not the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1150  In that case you could try downgrading to 3.0.12 until the issue  is fixed.